# AngularJS $q promises fullfillment depends on return?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using angularjs 1.6.1 with $q. I'm loading a bunch of data from and API. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding when promises are fulfilled. I'm doing something like this:

```
// controller
this.dataOnePromise = dataOneService.get().then(function (response){
    $scope.dataOne = response.data;
    return $scope.dataOne;
});

this.dataTwoPromise = dataTwoService.get().then(function (response){
    $scope.dataTwo = response.data;
    return $scope.dataTwo;
});

let promises = [this.dataOnePromise, this.dataTwoPromise];

$q.all(promises).then(function(response){
    // data is loaded!
    // I will access $scope.dataOne and $scope.dataTwo
});
```

All the services methods are like this:

```
 // service. Just the method, not the complete file
 get: function() {
    var defered = $q.defer();

    $http.get('my api endpoint').then(function(response) {
        defered.resolve(response);
    }, function(err) {
        defered.reject(err)
    });

    return defered.promise;
}
```

If I don't put explicitly the returns in the handlers of the then's when I call dataOneService and dataTwoService, am I having a race condition? (because the $q.all(promises) could get fulfilled by the service, but before the then handler which assigns the data to the scope)

I don't completely understand when is the $q.all(promises) fulfilled. It depends on the returns?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the doc
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

> all(promises);
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
> all of the input promises are resolved.
>
> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of
> values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key
> in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a
> rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same
> rejection value.

so to your questions,
**am I having a race condition?**
No, two calls are async and $q.all() waits until all the promises are resolved.

**I don't completely understand when is the $q.all(promises) fulfilled. It depends on the returns?**
Yes, again, $q.all() is fulfilled when all the promises are resolved.

========== extra=====

I personally recommend using hash for the promises so you can name your promises for later reference.

```
var promises = {};
promises.promiseA = ...;
promises.promiseB = ...;

$q.all(promises).then(function(result){
   console.log(result.promisesA);
   console.log(result.promisesB);

});
```

Comment: My doubt is if the promises get resolved by the resolve() in the service or by the return in the handlers?

Comment: You can assume it is always the lasted 'then' that triggers the fulfill. Since you have the return in dataOnePromise, it is by the return handlers. It is also helpful to set a break point inside all the 'then' and observe the behavior.

Comment: so even if you remove the "return $scope.dataOne;" it should still work.